# How can i use Unicode string key In Javascript Object?

Tags: javascript, unicode, javascript-objects, mozrepl

I want to use unicode string in Object as key, something as:

```
var t = {"姓名": "naitong"};
```

it's ok , t["姓名"] return "naitong"

but

```
Object.keys({"姓名": "naitong"})
```

I got "  ", a blank string

Anyone knowes why?

Editting:

I install firebug and try it in the console, it works.
Acctually i use mozrepl, so that i can editing and run javascript in emacs.
So This have something to do with mozrepl

I have confirm that mozrepl support only "7bit safe ASCII", to tranform unicode ,i have to json-encode it in emacs, as:

```
alert(Object.keys(JSON.parse("{\"\\u59d3\\u540d\":\"naitong\"}")))
```

This is my first question asked on stackoverflow, and i got quick resp.
Thank you all.

Comment: One one browser? On all browsers? Which?

Comment: What platform? If Windows, that'll be your problem: the C stdio interface that's (probably) used by emacs's connection to mozrepl is limited to the locale's code page, which on Windows is unfortunately never a UTF, so you can't get arbitrary Unicode down it.

Answer (score 3):

Works fine for me in the firebug console:

```
>>> Object.keys({"姓名": "naitong"})
["姓名"]
```

Maybe you are trying to display it on a page that uses a different charset which does not contain those symbols.

Comment: Chrome console also confirms success `> Object.keys({"姓名": "naitong"})` -> `["姓名"]`